# What does @Key mean in ORMLITE? (CLOSED)

Tags: android, ormlite

Could anyone tell me what does @Key mean in ORMLITE? I noticed some of the parameters have it, while some don't. How to know if I have to set a parameter with @Key? THX~
(CLOSED)

Comment: Where did you see this annotation?

Comment: Oh, then I should have made a mistake. It is from google-http-client, and I know what does it mean now.